# Problem with eclipse on 14.04 when not root

Tags: 14.04, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I downloaded eclipse IDE (for C/C++ developers) to my Linux box running 14.04 LTS.  I downloaded 64 bit version of JRE and 64 bit version of eclipse.  I can run fine as root (sudo), but when I try to run from my user account, I get this log file output:

```
!SESSION Tue May 31 09:01:11 PDT 2016
------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-05-31 09:01:11.777
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.100.v20150402-1551.jar
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-05-31 09:01:11.853
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Just to clarify:
`sudo eclipse`  works fine (eclipse at /opt/eclipse/eclipse is linked to /usr/local/bin).
`eclipse` and `/opt/eclipse/eclipse` return the error above. 
What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Vijay

Comment: do you mean when you open executable from the directory of eclipse ?

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I linked my eclipse executable at /opt/eclipse/eclipse to /usr/local/bin as suggested in Ubuntu documentation on eclipse install.  /usr/local/bin is in my path.  From my user space directory, I can do:
%> sudo eclipse    <<<< this works okay
but
%> eclipse    <<< gives me the error

Comment: please edit your question and append these information

Comment: what's happen when you run `/opt/eclipse/eclipse` ? without **sudo**

Comment: Running /opt/eclipse/eclipse without sudo - I get the same error

Comment: check this answer may help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/327551/eclipse-only-starts-with-sudo-command-from-terminal

Comment: what's the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` or `whereis java` if not `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` or `java - your version - oracle ` this the reason

Comment: Can you please run `find /opt/eclipse ! -readable -ls` as a regular user and post the output (including errors)? I suspect that some access permissions aren't set correctly and that prevents the class loader from finding all the necessary classes.